# How to get the name of class where an object is initialized c#

Tags: c#, class, inner-classes

I have a few classes. Lets say:

```
public class A
{
  public void SomeAction()
  {
    Debug.Write("I was declared in class: and my name is:");
  }
}
```

And

```
public class B
{
  public static A myClass = new A();
}

public class C
{
  public static A myClass = new A();
}

public class D
{
  public static A myClass = new A();
}
```

What I want "SomeAction" in class A to do is to print out which class it was initialized in.

So that for example in another class I called `C.myClass.SomeAction();` it would print out "I was declared in class `C` my name is `myClass`"

I hope this makes sense.

The reasons im doing this is for debugging within automated testing. I understand its not the best way to do things but its a requirement of the business.

Comment: You could add a property on the class that holds a string for "initialization location" then set the property right after you instantiate the object. Not sure if there's a better way, but it is a way. :P

Comment: Or you could use inheritance. Instead of B,C, and D having an instance of A, they could BE an instance of A.

Comment: "I understand its not the best way to do things but its a requirement of the business." - I love that line :-)

Comment: this wont work in a static method

Comment: Nevermind its not supposed to be static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requirement can be satisfied without inheritance or passing the object; we can get the name of the class that calls the constructor from within the body of the constructor by examining the stack.

```
public class A
{
    private string _createdBy;

    public void SomeAction()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("I was declared in class [{0}]", _createdBy);
    }

    public A()
    {
      var stackFrame = new StackFrame(1);
      var method = stackFrame.GetMethod();
      _createdBy = method.DeclaringType.Name;
    }
}
```

In terms of performance, I am assuming that you are not creating many instances of these objects. You could also predicate this on whether you are doing a DEBUG build or on some other setting, so that this stuff is skipped entirely in your production executables.

Comment: @Jonkers, be warned, this approach is ok for making some tests or loggers, but slow and not very legitimate otherwise.

Comment: Its only used for test automation. It basically produces log files that "non technical" testers can look at when a test fails as they dont have visual studio licences. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the same StackFrame to get the "name" of the defined class? so for example if I initialized and instance of the class as "myA", could I use the stackframe to get that?

Comment: @Jonkers You could not use `StackFrame` for this purpose. Consider that many different variables with different names can reference a single instance of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only reference an instance of class A in your other classes, I think there is no other way then setting a reference to the type which created class A, like eddie_cat already mentioned. You could do something like this:

```
public class B
{
  public static A myClass = new A(typeof(B));
}
```

And then your class A would look like:

```
public class A
{
  // store the parent type
  private Type mParentClass; 

  // provide parent type during construction of A
  public A(Type parentClass)
  {
     mParentClass = parentClass;
  }   

  // note that method cannot be static anymore, since every instance of A might 
  // have a different parent
  public void SomeAction()
  {
     // access field where parent type is stored.
     Debug.Write("I was declared in class: {0} and my name is:",mParentClass.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: For whatever reasons you need to know *parent* (holder or creator) of instance, it should be done as this answer suggest: by passing reference (or at least type) to parent via constructor or property (property - because I like [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx), though it will not guarantee parent will be set, but this case can be handled separately and may be, in fact, wanted). Not some dirty (and slow) stack manipulations.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the speed. Its not performance critical

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two choices. Either set a property in A, or inherit from A.  Personally, I prefer inheriting from A, because then A could just use GetType().

```
public class A
{
     public void SomeMethod()
     {
          Debug.Write(string.Format("I was declared in class: {0}",this.GetType()));
     }
}

public class B : A
{


}

var instanceOfB = new B();
instanceOfB.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Using inheritance for anything other than to represent a "is a kind of" relationship is never a good idea.

Comment: this.GetType() will just get the class A

Comment: @Jonkers No it won't.